# want to filter scanned jars for Spring component scanning

Tags: java, optimization, classpath, spring-4, component-scan

I am trying to optimize a massive Spring 4, Tomcat app.  Startup time is about 2 mins, and I'm wondering if there is a way to exclude certain jar files from being scanned?  e.g., I don't need commons-lang being scanned b/c Spring doeesn't care about that, but since you define the scanning based on context:component-scan/base-package in applicationContext.xml, i don't quite understand how I can do that.  Any ideas? Maybe do something with the resource-pattern attribute?

Comment: AFAIK, spring doesn't scan random jars. Related doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-classpath-scanning

Comment: how does it know where to look then? Sorry, i don't know much about any of this

Comment: org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider is used I think and with the config you tell what package should be scanned

Comment: what if you're using use-default-filters="true" though in context:component-scan? we seem to be using that as well as defining a ton of base packages

Comment: ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider can't know if certain JAR contains classes from the requested package or not, so it scans all JARs in the classpath by means of java.net.URLClassLoader#findResources.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 5, one can try a new feature, which generates a list of candidates at compile time. Reference: [1.10.9. Generating an index of candidate components](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-index)